# Visual Studio 2017 Launches Two Instances Of IE When Debugging A Single Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

My development machine was recently renamed and updated to Windows 10. While debugging a single ASP.Net project in VS 2017, I press F5 and two instances of the same page show up in my IE-11 Browser (Two Tabs - Same Page) which screws up the debugger. It works fine when I launch under chrome but I need to debug IE for now since it is still the  company standard.

Has any seen this behavior and is there a way to fix it?

Thanks for any insight - it's driving me crazy.

Comment: You can refer to [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/visual-studio-web-developer-express-starting-two-instances-of-internet-explorer-and-throwing-an-error) to check the Visual Studio browsers list whether you have added multiple IE browser Instances. And, here is a [similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0fbd0352-af53-4b8b-8526-ea364a3e4b93/2-browsers-open-in-visual-studio-web-site-development-when-running-without-debugging?forum=vsdebug) you could check it. If still not working, try to reset the Visual Studio environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of head scratching, I finally came up with the solution and it was one of those things where it was simple. After the Windows 10 upgrade occurred, the software went and reset all of my IE 11 browser settings. There is an option on the first option page that says "Start with tabs from last session". This was selected and every time a new VS browser window fired up it went and created a tab from my previous session. I selected the other option "Start with home page" and the problem went away.